# UITableViewCell bottom information text

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

How can add some information text ('Please note that...') to the bottom of a uitableviewcell, just like in this image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section` a try:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return @"This text is below the TableView!";
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Additional documentation can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3atitleForFooterInSection%3a).

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking at in that screen shot is not part of any UITableViewCell. It is the table's footer (a feature of the table). Try making a UILabel containing your desired content and setting it to the table's `tableFooterView`.